# Creating a table of schedules in excel from 3 references

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to create a table that's easy to view the schedules from a raw data.
The raw data looks like the below

```
Jobname: deletearchive
Start_time: 00:00,01:00,23:45
Days_of_week: su,mo,sa
```

I would like to put them into columns with header su and time from 00:00 to 23:00 for each day. One challenge i see is I need consider 3 criteria - day(su to mo), time(some are not at 00 minutes but need to be round down) and the jobname. I have 500 jobnames with different schedules.

```
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|    JOBNAME    |  su   |  su   |  su   |  mo   |  mo   |  mo   |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|               | 00:00 | 01:00 | 23:00 | 00:00 | 01:00 | 23:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| deletearchive | yes   | yes   | 23:45 | yes   | yes   | 23:45 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| JOB2          |       |       |       |       |       |       |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| JOB3          |       |       |       |       |       |       |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Comment: Is there a limit on how many start_times are? I think with some helping columns you should be able to do it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: start_time varies, some have 4 schedules. I tried doing simple vlookup with 3 references (concatenate) but I am stuck with multiple schedule on some jobs. It's easy if one job has one schedule.

Comment: You should split the job based on schedules using helping columns, and then you can use VLOOKUP() or INDEX()+MATCH()

Comment: but there is no pattern on job schedule. there's a lot of schedul theres daily, wf,weekend only. Having said I have 500 jobs. this is impossible